# supplying liquidity + sniping own coin in same bundle

Tags: uniswap, blocks, flashbots, liquidity

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0d21d70e031089ab3e5b8083a84f122d5e995033c666dd7ce7cff982b5ba7c77

it looks like this transaction has Supply liquidity and swap Eth for its token all in one bundle.

can anyone break this down for me please?

also, is it necessary to check https://flashbots-explorer.marto.lol/?block=18235726 to understand this specific transaction even more deeper?

is it a coincidence that the token was launched on a flashbots block?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a coincidence, they've purposefully hidden their transaction from public mem pool using flashbots. But they aren't using a bundle to do it across multiple transactions.

Looks like they have created a contract and initiated everything from the constructor.